# Android NFC P2P Reply message

Tags: android, nfc, android-beam, nfc-p2p

I am designing a simple app trying to leverage NFC on android.

I want to beam a message to a device, and have the RECEIVER beam a response message to the SENDER.  This needs to happen without requiring the receiver to voluntarily "Touch to beam"

Any ideas for this?

Comment: No, this is not possible. You must go through Android Beam to communicate via Android devices using NFC.

Comment: any ideas for how to auto click the android beam notification?

Comment: No; I seriously doubt the developers would leave such a vulnerability in after attempting to prevent people from abusing NFC.

Comment: Bummer.  This was the conclusion I had reached but I was hoping for some alternate ideas.